# Select query from 2 table using entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

```
 select p.ProduitNom,v.VonduDate,p.ProduitPrix from Produits p,Vondus v
 where p.ProduitId = v.ProduitId and p.CentreId=1
```

How to do this request in entity framework ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that as shown below.

**Inner Join :**

```
from p in db.Produits
join v in db.Vondus  on p.ProduitId equals v.ProduitId
where p.CentreId=1
select new {
               ProduitNom = p.ProduitNom,
               VonduDate = v.VonduDate,
               ProduitPrix = p.ProduitPrix
           }
```

If you would like to learn,you can refer this : [**Queries in LINQ to Entities**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399367(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: dont give same result

Comment: hehe.. this is weekend no ? all are Free today  :D @Div

Comment: var query = (from p in db.Produits
                         join v in db.Vondus on p.ProduitId equals v.ProduitId
                         where p.CentreId == centre.CentreId
                         select new
                         {
                             date = v.VonduDate,
                             nom = p.ProduitNom,
                             prix = p.ProduitPrix
                         }).ToList();

Comment: :D at least tell to OP for try @Sampath

Comment: Yes,I did that with a reference link :D @Div

Comment: Thanks :) Have a Nice weekend ! @Div

Comment: The query provided by @Sampath is ok. What is the error?

Comment: var query =  (from p in db.Produits
                         join v in db.Vondus on p.ProduitId equals v.ProduitId
                         where p.CentreId == centre.CentreId
                         select new
                         {
                             nom = p.ProduitNom,
                             date = v.VonduDate,
                             prix = p.ProduitPrix
                         }).ToList();

Comment: what is this `p.CentreId == centre.CentreId` ? on your original query you has put it as `p.CentreId=1` no ? why this difference ?

Comment: I didn't get you ? can you provide more info ?

Comment: how to browse this query

Comment: do you want to see the generated `TSQL` query of above `EF query` or result of it ?

Comment: just put a debug on the query and see it using visual studio.

Comment: your original question was about LINQ query.So you got the solution for it.please `accept this solution` as an answer firstly. After that open a new question with your new requirement.then you'll have better response from the community.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Join`:

EDIT:
You should have a context to connect with Database first, or else, at least 2 lists:

```
List<Produits> Produits = new List<Produits>();
List<Vondus> Vondus = new List<Vondus>();
```

Then using below lambda expression:

```
var res = Produits.Join(Vondus, p => p.ProduitId, v => v.ProduitId,
                    (p, v) => new { p, v })
                    .Where(pv => pv.p.ProduitId == pv.v.ProduitId && pv.p.CentreId == 1)
                    .Select(pv => new { pv.p.ProduitNom, pv.v.VonduDate, pv.p.ProduitPrix)
                    .ToList();
```

The `res` will be a list containts of `ProduitNom`, `VonduDate` and `ProduitPrix`

Comment: vp in vp.v.VonduDate,vp.p.ProduitPrix give an error

Comment: @MohamedElgarnaoui if you want to use my method, `res` will be access as a List<object>` . Example `res[0].ProduitNom`